# Why does a single object written to two different Streams represent two distinct objects when read back?

Tags: java, serialization

The title tells my need and here the following is code that I'm use:

#### Test Case

```
SameObjectDifferentStreams same = new SameObjectDifferentStreams(); 
ObjectOutputStream out1 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file1"));
ObjectOutputStream out2 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file2"));

out1.writeObject(same);
out1.close();

out2.writeObject(same);
out2.close();

System.out.println("The Original reference is :" + same.toString());

oin1 = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("file1"));
oin2 = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("file2"));

SameObjectDifferentStreams same1 = 
    (SameObjectDifferentStreams) oin1.readObject();
System.out.println("The First Instance is :" + same1.toString());

SameObjectDifferentStreams same2 = 
    (SameObjectDifferentStreams) oin2.readObject();
System.out.println("The Second Instance is :" + same2.toString());
```

#### Output

```
The Original reference is :serialization.SameObjectDifferentStreams@9304b1
The First Instance is :serialization.SameObjectDifferentStreams@190d11
The Second Instance is :serialization.SameObjectDifferentStreams@a90653
```

Comment: Depending on the situation, custom serialization of either the shared object itself, or the objects with references to the shared object, may allow you to get the behavior you desire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write object to stream you actually *serialize* it, i.e. write its data only. Then when you read it you read the data and create new object. It is like if you invoke `new MyObject()` with appropriate constructor arguments. Obviously the new object is created here.

If you read the same serialized object twice you create new instance twice. These 2 instances are equal, i.e. all their fields are equal, but the references are different, so the expression `o1==o2` returns false while (if you implement reasonable `equals()` method) `o1.equals(o2)` returns true.

Comment: The class constructor is called during deserialization right?

Comment: @Rekha No constructor is called during deserialization. Plenty of magic under the hoods.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is called [EQ](http://www.eros-os.org/pipermail/cap-talk/2006-December/006267.html) in distributed computing and some systems do try to solve it, but Java deserialization does not.

Imagine the two different streams are in two different Java Virtual Machines in two different processes.  The two different reads would have to result in two different objects since there is no way for the stream implementation to realize that these bytes in this file correspond to this object already in memory but in another process.

The same problem exists when the two streams are in the same virtual machine -- the mapping from bytes to an object in memory is unspecifiable because Java serialization does not assign a globally unique address to an object and even if it did, there would be no way to enforce uniqueness even within a single vat without a global weak map of objects containing a key entry for every serialized/deserialized object.  Java serialization simply punts on preserving object identity between different deserialization sessions.

Answer (score 4):

If they weren't two distinct objects, using the objects sanely would be impossible. Consider an analogy in the physical world: I write a letter and mail it to you. You start reading it. Then I start changing the letter to send it to someone else and *your* copy of the letter starts changing!

Comment: ALL THE GUYS WHO HAVE GIVEN ANSWERS HERE ARE AWESOME.GREAT AND AWESOME ANSWERS

Answer (score 2):

They are different because when you write an object you write a copy of that object. When you read it back, that copy is placed inside a new object allocated in memory. If you compare same1 and same2 they will be different objects in memory.

I suspect that somewhere you are doing a comparison like

```
same1 == same2
```

and it returns false. They are different objects in memory. Try to override the equals method and compare some fields for equality.